# Как считать все объекты записанные в один файл в Java?

Tags: java

Есть у меня свой собственный класс. Я с помощью `ObjectOutputStream` записал в файл много объектов. Как мне их теперь все с файла извлечь, или хотя бы сделать поиск по полю объектов из файла?

Answer (score 3):

Записать объект некоторого класса в файл можно реализовав в данном классе интерфейс `Serializable`. Например, есть класс, который представляет собой точку в пространстве, которая имеет название:

```
public class Point implements Serializable {
    private String mName;
    private int mX;
    private int mY;
    private int mZ;

    public Point(String name, int x, int y, int z) {
        mName = name;
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mZ = z;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return mX;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return mY;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return mZ;
    }
}
```

Записать несколько объектов данного класса в файл можно, например, так:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("temp.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

points.add(new Point("First point", 1, 2, 3));
points.add(new Point("Second point", 2, 3, 4));
points.add(new Point("Third point", -5, 10, 16));

for (Point point : points) {
    oos.writeObject(point);
}

oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

А прочитать из файла вот так:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("temp.txt");
ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

while (true) {
    try {
        points.add((Point) oin.readObject());
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        break;
    }
}

fis.close();
```